# Probability of finding same wrong answer

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there are two students who are asked to independently solve a question with 4 possible answers. Their capability of finding the right answer is not 100%. Let's say that they have $p_1$ and $p_2$ probability of finding the right answer. So, the probability of both of them finding the correct answer is $p_1 p_2$. There is only one correct answer and the rest of the wrong answers are statistically indifferent (i.e. no wrong answer is more likely than other).

What is the probability of them finding the same wrong answer ? Is it $(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdot\frac{1}{3}$ ?

If yes, is the following reasoning correct to explain it ?

$P$(Both Same $\cap$ Both Wrong) = $P$(Both Wrong) $P$(Both Same | Both Wrong)

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Is only one answer right out of four possibilities? three wrong answers? is no answer a wrong answer too?

Comment: @msm as I said, there is only one correct answer and the rest of the wrong answers are statistically indifferent. Let's say there is no option to not give an answer. Both give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the probability of them finding the same wrong answer ? Is it $(1−p_1)(1−p_2)\cdot\tfrac 13$ ?

Yes.

> If yes, is the following reasoning correct to explain it ?
>   $$P(\text{Both Same} ∩ \text{Both Wrong}) ~=~ P(\text{Both Wrong})\cdot P(\text{Both Same} \mid \text{Both Wrong})$$

It is.

...

There's not much else that can be said.